# Nav div not aligning right in IE9, fine in Chrome and FF

Tags: internet-explorer-9

I think I may be a bit daft here but I cannot figure out why my nav has an ugly gap to the right in IE9

http://i46.tinypic.com/10nu5w5.jpg

It looks fine in FF and Chrome, exactly as I want whereby the margin is the same as the one before the logo on the left.

http://tinypic.com/r/2v8mmty/6 and jsfiddle is [jsfiddle.net/KNuEp/1](http://jsfiddle.net/KNuEp/1)

This is obviously an IE thing. Bascially in the HEADER DIV (which is in a 960px wrapper div), I have a SITETITLE div, which contains the logo floated left and a NAV div, containing the navigation ul floated right. I can paste some code if it will help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix your issue

**Replace by this**

```
<div id="header" class="clearfix">
        <div id="sitetitle" class="clearfix">
            <a href="index.html"><img src="images/bathroom-logo.png"></a>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thanks - I tried both of those ideas but no luck. I can't paste the HTML or CSS here as it exceeds the max character length!

Comment: #nav{float:right;font-family:'Droid Sans',Verdana,Tahoma,sans-serif;text-align:center;}
#nav ul{list-style:none;margin:30px 30px 26px 20px;float:right;}
#nav ul li{background:none!important;display:inline-block;text-align:right;height:auto;line-height:25px;margin-bottom:0;margin-left:25px;position:relative;}
#nav ul li a{color:#797777;display:block;font-size:10px;padding-top:0;text-transform:uppercase;}
#nav ul li a:hover{color:#111;}
#nav ul li a.current{color:#000;}

Comment: please jsfiddle it with html.. I can't understand

Comment: i don't know what jsfiddle is - i will take a look and get right back - thanks for your patience

Comment: @AndyAshwin open jsfiddle then copy at html portion the html pages and at css your css..

Comment: Thanks. Where can I see the fix? I used the code in jsfiddle but it seems the same!

Comment: Can I see your new fiddle have you copy it.as it working fine

Comment: Did you just change that bit (in your edited post)? That looks the same as what I started with.

Comment: Yeah I edited...Please refresh it ok I am copy here <div id="header" class="clearfix">
        <div id="sitetitle" class="clearfix">
            <a href="index.html"><img src="images/bathroom-logo.png"></a>
        </div>

Comment: My original code is <div id="header" class="clearfix"><div id="sitetitle" class="clearfix"><a href="index.html"><img src="images/bathroom-logo.png"</a></div> - surely that is exactly the same as what you have posted???

Comment: Please use this <img src="images/bathroom-logo.png"> ">" is you missed out and IE check all thing clearly that your float was not correct

Comment: Hahahaha! 

Sorry, I AM an idiot! How did I not spot that? Thank you x1000 for helping me with this and having unlimited patience!!!

Comment: My pleasure I also devoted my 30 min in this figuring out what was wrong...btw what you do?

Comment: I am a design student. I only do a small amount of web design. This was one of those problems that is hard to spot! I should have spotted the fact that the </a> was not green in DW, indicating an open tag! Thanks man!

Comment: My Pleasure dude...don't worry feel free to ask genuine question